# Postgresql Program Limit Exceeded errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I was running some update queries on rails console for activerecord postgresql database and it was giving following error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::ProgramLimitExceeded: ERROR: number of array dimensions exceeds the maximum allowed)`. Why this issue came and How to solve this.

Comment: Could you put some code snippet of your update?

Comment: The only postgres limit for arrays I know of is the 1GB limit on value size. Weirdly enough, I can't seem to find any documentation on a maximum number of dimensions for arrays (as the error would suggest)... From the postgres docs: `declaring the array size or number of dimensions in CREATE TABLE is simply documentation; it does not affect run-time behavior.`